# How to connect valid websocket address

Tags: android, websocket

I have list of web  socket server addresses.I stored it in Array List.In Array List there is only one valid web socket address.I need to connect that valid address.I used for loop but when valid address is in last index in array list its working fine.but when valid address before last index its not connecting.how to do this.

Comment: share your code

Comment: @sheik Its not a proper way to ask question. I don't have enough reputation else I down-vote your question. No body can suggest you without knowing your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect WebSocket in Android using OkHttp

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button start;
private TextView output;
private OkHttpClient client;

private final class Socket extends WebSocketListener {
private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;

@Override
public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
  webSocket.send("Hello,  !");
  webSocket.send("your text ?");
  webSocket.send(ByteString.decodeHex("xyz"));
  webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, "bye!");
}

@Override
public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
  output("Receiving : " + text);
}

@Override
public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
  output("Receiving bytes : " + bytes.hex());
}

@Override
public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
  webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null);
  output("Closing : " + code + " / " + reason);
}

@Override
public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
  output("Error : " + t.getMessage());
}
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
client = new OkHttpClient();

start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    start();
  }
});

}
 private void start() {
Request request = new  Request.Builder().url("ws://echo.websocket.org").build();
EchoWebSocketListener listener = new EchoWebSocketListener();
WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
 }
private void output(final String txt) {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    output.setText(output.getText().toString() + "\n\n" + txt);
  }
});
}
 }
```

Comment: I need to connect dynamic.

Comment: assume that you have four web socket address.how do you connect valid address

Comment: @sheik did you use this in your code ?
web_socket.setKeepAlive(true).

Comment: this is perfectly working when i use static websocket server address.But i need to connect dynamic websocket address